# Error 404 after starting the node application and visiting localhost:1337

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have node application that uses sails. I start the application using `node app.js`, but upon visiting localhost:1337, I get a 404.

Comment: Can your project start with `sails lift`? This launch method shouldn't generally be modified in sails if this is indeed the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `node app.js` try `sails lift`.